# Python subprocess capture output of bash code in parentheses

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I have a shell script that I run in a `subprocess.popen()` and would like to capture the output of that script and send it line by line into a logger object. The issue is that the output from the subprocess is captured by the parentheses `()`, and I never see the output. Has anyone here ever seen this happen, and would you be able to guide me on how to best do this?

The code takes a backup on a remote server and stores it locally. The parentheses are needed to encapsulate the ssh-agent in case more than one are open at the same time.

The bash code

```bash
( \
  eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null; \
  ssh-add -q /home/borgs/.ssh/borg-client_key; \
  echo $borgPassword | \
    ssh -p ${port} -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${user}@${ipAddress} \
    "BORG_PASSPHRASE=\$(cat) \
    borg \
    --rsh 'ssh -p 9270 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
    create \
    --verbose \
    --filter AME \
    --list \
    --stats \
    --show-rc \
    --compression lz4 \
    --exclude-caches \
    ssh://borgs@${ip_address}/~/${hostname}::$hostname-$backupTime $locations";
  kill "${SSH_AGENT_PID}"; \
) >&1
```

The python code

```py
def takeBackup(server, lg):
    print(f"Taking backup of {server['hostname']}")
    locationString = " ".join(server['locations'])
    print(
        "Running create-backup.sh command: create-backup.sh",
        f"{server['hostname']} {server['ip-address']} '{locationString}'"
    )
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "./create-backup.sh",
            server['hostname'],
            server['ip-address'],
            server['borgPassword'],
            locationString
        ],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    for line in process.stdout:
        line = line.decode().rstrip('\n')
        lg.print_info(line)
    process.wait()
    print(process.returncode)
```

Comment: Why the pipe, instead of simply writing `BORG_PASSPHRASE=$borgPassword`?

Comment: @chepner I am not sure I was following the documentation on the borg website https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/pull-backup.html

Comment: I don't see anything that's capturing the output in parentheses. `>&1` is a no-op, it redirects stdout to stdout (I think it's a typo for `2>&1`, which combines stderr into stdout.

Comment: `>&1` : redirect stdout to stdout ???

Comment: Remember to quote variables in case they contain special characters: `echo "$borgPassword"`

Comment: Using a double-quoted string for the argument passed to ssh as the code to run remotely in your shell script is... not great. It means your variable expansions happen _before_ ssh is run, so all your variables' values are parsed as code by the remote shell. If some joker asks you to back up a directory `/home/joker/$(rm -rf ~)/whatever`, that could lead to a very bad day.

Comment: BTW, you **don't** need the parenthesis (which are irrelevant to the problem besides; you'd have the same issues without them). Each `subprocess.Popen` instance is already in its own shell; starting a new subshell doesn't do anything beyond that. You'd need them if you were sourcing the script into an interactive shell, sure, but even if you're just running the code as a _subprocess_ of an interactive shell, that's still enough to have a completely distinct scope.

Comment: Also, sending a sensitive password to the stdin of a session you open with `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is... not a good idea. It means anyone who does a man-in-the-middle attack can collect that password free-of-charge.

Comment: And anyhow, for a single key sitting unencrypted on disk there's no reason to use an agent at all; `ssh -i /path/to/key` and can skip the `ssh-agent` creation and the `ssh-add` entirely.

Comment: And **no**, `( )` does not capture anything; the claimed issue in the text of the question is impossible. You may well be getting no output, but it has nothing to do with `( )` doing a capture.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ya I removed them and its still giving no output. I am not sure why it's doing this. When I used subprocess.run() it would print the output but I could not grab each line for parsing and error handling.

Comment: One thing you're doing right now that can mess things up is setting `stderr=PIPE` but never consuming from the pipe. If the subprocess tries to write something to stderr it can get blocked and never go on to get to do anything else.